# Where do I put my downloaded Trackmania maps so I can play them?

Tags: trackmania-forever

I recently downloaded a few extra maps for the free version Trackmania, called *Trackmania Nations Forever*.

Where should i put these maps so that i can access them from within the game (through the browse option). I will also like to host them in a LAN environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside:

```
My Documents\TrackMania\Tracks\Challenges
```

For further information about other kinds of files, see *File locations* tutorial from *Mania Creative* (formely *TM Creative*): [page 1](http://tutorials.mania-creative.com/tm_general_filelocations/index-eng-1) and [page 2](http://tutorials.mania-creative.com/tm_general_filelocations/index-eng-2)

Comment: I Actually figured it out. But thanks for the links!

Comment: For TrackMania 2, it is `Documents\ManiaPlanet\Maps\Downloaded` (just in case someone comes here looking for this)